# UICollectionView crashes when item size is automatic and header is shown

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I encounter a weird error that when I want to set the `estimatedItemSize` property of the `UICollectionView` to `UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize` and show a section header at the same time.

With the below code, the app can show the `UICollectionView` properly. However, once the user scrolls on the `UICollectionView`, the app crashes with a recursive call to the function `updateVisibleCellsNow`.

I find a workaround solution from another StackOverflow question by setting the `estimatedItemSize` from `automaticSize` to `none`. However, I want to keep the auto-layout features set at the `UICollectionViewCell` instead of calculating the cell height myself. Is there any better solution? Thank you.

[image]

Here is my code about the ViewController

```swift
import UIKit
class DemoCollectionViewController: UIViewController {
    
    lazy private var collectionView: UICollectionView = { [weak self] in
        guard let strongSelf = self else { return UICollectionView() }
        
        // Setup of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`
        let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        

        // ********* This is the line that causes crash *********
        flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
        // ******************************************************

        flowLayout.headerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: getScreenWidth(), height: 44.0)
        flowLayout.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true
        
        // Setup of `UICollectionView`
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: flowLayout).disableFrameToAutoLayout()
        collectionView.dataSource = strongSelf
        collectionView.register(ProfileThumbnailCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellId")
        collectionView.register(UICollectionReusableView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "headerId")
        
        return collectionView
    }()
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Setup of the UICollectionView
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            collectionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            collectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor),
        ])
    }
}

extension DemoCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 20
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! ProfileThumbnailCollectionViewCell
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .yellow
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

        switch kind {
        case UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader:
            let supplementaryView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "headerId", for: indexPath)
            supplementaryView.backgroundColor = .red
            return supplementaryView
        default:
            return UICollectionReusableView()
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my code about the `ProfileThumbnailCollectionViewCell`:

```swift
class ProfileThumbnailCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    private let profileThumbnailImageView: UIImageView = {
        let profileThumbnailImageView = UIImageView()
        profileThumbnailImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        profileThumbnailImageView.backgroundColor = .red
        profileThumbnailImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 60
        profileThumbnailImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        return profileThumbnailImageView
    }()
    
    private let editPenButton: UIButton = {
        let editPenButton = UIButton()
        editPenButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        editPenButton.backgroundColor = .mainGreen
        editPenButton.layer.cornerRadius = 16
        editPenButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
        return editPenButton
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        // Content View
        contentView.backgroundColor = .yellow
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
        ])
        
        // Profile Thumbnail ImageView
        contentView.addSubview(profileThumbnailImageView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            profileThumbnailImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor),
            profileThumbnailImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120),
            profileThumbnailImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120),
            profileThumbnailImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 25),
            profileThumbnailImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -25)
        ])
        
        // Edit thumbnail pen ImageView
        contentView.addSubview(editPenButton)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            editPenButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32),
            editPenButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32),
            editPenButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor),
            editPenButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("This class should be inited from code instead of a nib file; init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: whats is there in the updateVisibleCellsNow. can you share the full code..

Comment: Hi, the `updateVisibleCellsNow` is a private function of the `UICollectionView`. Therefore, I cannot access the code.

Comment: I have a similar problem, and noticed that setting `sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds` to false fixes the crash. Didn't find any alternative for now.

Comment: EDIT: Switching to a CompositionalLayout seems to fix the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

call registerNib in ViewDidLoad

```
func registerNib(){
 let nib = UINib(nibName: "ProfileThumbnailCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil)
 self.collectionView.register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ProfileThumbnailCollectionViewCell")
}
```

Comment: hi, there are no differences between creating a `UICollectionViewCell` by NIB or by code. The error still comes out.

Answer (score 0):

After investigating for a few hours, I accidentally found a workaround solution but surely this should not be considered as the final solution.

```swift
class ProfileThumbnailCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        // Content View
        contentView.backgroundColor = .yellow

        // ******** This is the weird point ********
        let targetCellWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 1


        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: targetCellWidth)
        ])
    }
}
```

The `UICollectionView` does not throw any error and displays both the header view and the `UICollectionView` properly.

If you can find any idea about this situation, please leave your comment here. Your information is highly appreciated! Thank you!